# Media keys stopped working after 7x upgrade

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, horus, multimedia

I'll have to test by booting an older live CD to confirm, but I'm pretty sure my media keys stopped working after the 7x Horus upgrade.

They are actived via Fn-key combination strokes such as Fn-F10 for mute, Fn-F11 lower volume and Fn-12 for increase volume. This is a pretty old Zareason laptop that is based on Pegatron B14Y hardware.

If the 'showkey --keycodes' command in virtual terminal is to be believed, the Fn-F## keystrokes straight up aren't even recognized by the kernel. Naked Function key presses are, as are other Fn-F## keystrokes, such as Fn-F5 which is correctly interpreted as lower brightness key. So some Fn keystroke combos work, others don't. It seems to be limited to all the Fn media keystroke combos. This includes start/pause, stop, skip track fwd and backwards.

Most solutions I've found online have to do with updating the BIOS but that ain't going to happen with this device.

Comment: Some digging online reveals almost nothing about the keyboards on those devices. If a firmware update is not feasible, you may need to extract the key codes with an older Live USB/DVD and then add them to the current installation. However, if `showkey` isn't registering them, then there may be something else going on. Have you confirmed that the correct keyboard layout is being used?

Comment: I use the dvorak keyboard layout, so perhaps that has something to do with it. I've always used the dvorak layout though, and like I said, I'm pretty these same media keys worked in 6x releases Jolnir and Odin